# Vertically align components by baseline in a QHBoxLayout

Tags: macos, qt, qt-designer

I'm using Qt Designer to lay out a form with *QLabel*, *QLineEdit* and *QComboBox* controls inside of *QFormLayout* and *QHBoxLayout* containers. What do I need to do to have the controls aligned vertically by their text's baselines?

When previewing the dialog on Max OS X, the different controls do not align by their baseline. The following example is using *QHBoxLayout*, but the same happens with *QFormLayout*:

[image: Example on Max OS X]

Notice how the underscores are not on the same vertical position.

I'm looking for a solution that will work with all widget combinations where baseline adjustment is applicable and where the adjustment is done automatically based on style, platform, widget combination, widget sizes and font settings. Something comparable with *CSS*'s `vertical-align: baseline;`.

**Update**

I've done the same test on Windows XP and also applied [RA.s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041094/402281) of using a style sheet. But that does not seem to change any of the placement of the controls or their text.

[image: Example on Windows XP]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to change the vertical alignment of the QLabels.  In Qt Designer, you can accomplish this by clicking on the `QLabel`, then adjusting the label's `alignment` property.  In this case, I believe that changing the vertical alignment to `AlignBottom` might fix your problem.  If that doesn't work, the label also has a `margin` property that you can adjust.

**Update**

Consider using [Qt's style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) for your application.  The following style sheet achieved the desired result on the platforms that I could test on (which, unfortunately, does not include OS X):

```
QLabel, QComboBox, QLineEdit
{
   background-position: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Setting the vertical alignment property to `AlignBottom` sets the `QLabel`'s text one pixel too low for a `QComboBox` and two pixels too low for a `QLineEdit`. I don't think fiddling with the `margin` property or manually adjusting the `QLineEdit`'s position is an acceptable solution because I imagine these setting will only be valid for a single style/platform, aside from the _manual_ part.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific on how I'd like those adjustments to be applied.

Comment: @Feuermurmel I've updated my answer to provide what is hopefully a more robust solution.

Comment: On which platform have you tested this? Setting the style sheet does not seem to change the placement of any of the controls. I'm testing this on Windows XP (Windows style set to classic) and Mac OS X 10.6. Thanks!

Comment: @Feuermurmel I've tested this on Linux (with virtually every style) using Qt 4.7, though reading the documentation it's not clear if this property is intended to work with background images, or the contents of the widgets themselves.  Playing around on Windows 7 with Qt 4.8, the only style sheet property that seems to have any effect is the "margin" property, though it seems to have nasty results.  Nevertheless, you might want to give that a try.  It's possible that system-level themes are getting in the way of everything else.